# How do I create user-defined JLabel,JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Based on the title, how do I create a dynamic size of JLabel and JTextfield determined by user ?

I have a `Main.java` which takes user input and I'm creating a JFrame on another file (`Design3.java`) but the problem I encounter is how do I pass the value from the `Main.java` to `Design3.java`

Here is my code for the `Design3.java` file. Basically I'm stucked because the value I passed from `Main.java` the scope of the variable last for the Design3 method. How do I make it global because I need to create `JLabel` globally.

```
int numberOfSellers;

Label[] l = new Label[numberOfSellers];

public class Design3 {

    int numberOfSellers;

    Design3 nOS = new Design3();

    public Design3( int number_of_sellers )
    {
        nOS.setNumberOfSellers(number_of_sellers);

        JFrame newWindow = new JFrame("Test");

        newWindow.setVisible(true);
        newWindow.setSize(500,500);
        newWindow.setLayout(null);
    }

    public void setNumberOfSellers(int num)
    {
        this.numberOfSellers = num;
    }
```

}

Comment: You could have the dimensions be fields of `Design3` and then have the values initialized by passing them as arguments through the constructor. Also don't use a null layout with Swing; it is important to learn the layout managers

Comment: I passed the user input value to the constructor of the class but then again, the scope of the variable last for the methods only, how do I set it globally? I'm just introduced to JFrame and still learning.

Comment: You don't want to use global variables. You will probably want to learn and use the Observer Design Pattern to allow one class to listen for changes to another class.

Comment: Please describe your problem a little better with a little more detail. Also, what does this Main class look like?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `Design3 nOS = new Design3();` in the `Design3` class seems like a design issue right ?

Comment: @LittleChild: indeed it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question in a nutshell is: How can I have an object of one class change the state of an object in another class. Usually that translates into having one object change the state of the field(s) of another object.

Comments:

- There is no one-size fits all answer for this as it is a very broad and overly general question. That is why we are asking for clarification of your problem since the more specific your question, usually the more clear the answer.
- General ways to change the state of an object's field including via a constructor parameter. So you can give your GUI an int field say `numberOfFoo` and then give it a constructor parameter to match, and then when one class creates an instance of the other, it can pass the proper number into the first class's constructor.
- Or you could use a setter method such as `setFoo(int foo)` where one class can pass the number into the other class.

If you have a more specific question, then you'll have to delineate it further. For instance, if you want one object to monitor another object's field and respond to changes, then again as per my comment, you'll want to use some type of observer design pattern mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

> Based on the title, how do I create a dynamic size of JLabel and
>   JTextfield determined by user ?

What are you trying to do ? You can look into creating a custom class that extends `JLabel` and another custom class which extends `JTextField`.

Second, why does `Design3`  have an instance of `Design3` ? I am sensing a lot of bad design here.

Third, look into the `Swing MVC` architecture.

Comment: 1) I'm wanted to create a dynamic size of JLabel and JTextField. For example let say user input 2, I create 2 JLabel and 2 JTextField.
2) I'm lost so I try an error for it.

Comment: @user273371: you're confusing me. You mention in one part of your comment above that you want to create a dynamic **size** for a JLabel and a JTexztField, and in another part, you want to create a dynamic **number** of components. Well, which is it? And why ignore my comments above in your original question? You really need to put more effort into clarifying and asking a better question if you want better answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear. Easy say, for example when an user input 2, I create 2 JLabel and JTextField.